# Unable to install packages in R console

Tags: r

I am getting the following error when installing packages in R , can anyone please provide me a solution for this? I have tried the solutions posted on other posts but none of it has helped.

```
install.packages("ggplot2")

--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: failed to download mirrors file (cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv');
```

Comment: Do you choose a mirror? Which one? Have you tried a different one? Are you behind a firewall by any chance?

Comment: Probably a popup window appears but is behind another window.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
install.packages('ggplot2', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

Comment: It has also not worked. Same error :- unable to open the URL.Any other alternative?

Comment: Are you able to make outgoing connections through R with a different function, such as `download.file()`? What version of R are you running (`sessionInfo()`)?